# Helper class of X shared among different java projects, each one using different version of X

Tags: java, maven, classloader

Suppose I have wrote a *helper* class for kafka client. The helper class is *agnostic* to the **version** of kafka client (there are no API changes). My question is what is the best practice in java for such situation, I mean that I cannot build a jar containing my helper class because it should contain dependency to some version of kafka and this is problematic because I want to use the same helper class in two different projects, one using kafka:0.9.0 and another using kafka:1.0.0.

thanks ahead.

Comment: Why couldn't you? Building a jar containing your helper class will build a jar containing your helper class. Not the kafka client classes. So a user of your jar will just use your jar, and whatever version of the kafka client they want.

Comment: Because my helper class contains a reference to kafka classes, I cannot build a jar without specifying kafka client dependency.

Comment: Define the dependency with scope `provided` ?

Comment: @AlexBelous as Taylor's answer explains, that doesn't prevent the user of your library  to choose to use another version of the kafka client.

Comment: However it makes him to set kafka dependency even if he is not using my helper class

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, in the helper's dependencies, I specify the minimum value I choose to support, and expect that consumers will explicitly pull in a different version if they want.

**EDITED TO ADD:**

Another option is to set the minimum supported version with a `scope` of `provided`.  This means any consumer will NEED to pull in a version of Kafka for their code to compile.

Maven dependency scope docs:
https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope

Comment: Using provided seems indeed a good way to go. You'll be able to compile and publish your library and your other projects will define any Kafka version they want. The limitation is that it becomes *required* to define a Kafka dependency on your other projects, unlike classic dependencies where such transitive dependencies will be available by default